# Is there any method to combine 2 pandas dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to combine 2 dataframe. However, it has one problem. How do I combine 2 table if 1 table value have to duplicate to another table.

I have tried, pandas.concat and pandas.merge.

```
df1={'id':[1]}
df2={'Brand':['volvo','audi'],
     'Price':[20,000,30,000]}

pd.concat([df1],[df2])
```

I expect the table will show as below:

```
id  Brand   Price
1   volvo   20,000
1   audi    30,000
```

It mean the id 1 has both car.

Comment: What should happen if, for example, there were two IDs?

Comment: `pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)`?

Comment: Your example `df`s are `dict`s. Do you want to make single dataframe from multiple **dict**s?

Comment: nope, i forget to put these code, person=pd.DataFrame(df1)
car=pd.DataFrame(df2). It only has 1 ID. So I problem with how do produce  the final dataframe like my expected table.

Answer (score 0):

You have to decide how you want to merge, if there are multiple values. If there is just 1, then you can simply assign like:

```
df1['key'] = 1
df2['key'] = 1
```

Perform a merge on the temp key, then drop the temporary key:

```
df1.merge(df2).drop(columns=['key'])
```

Output:

```
 id  Brand  Price
 0   1  volvo  20000
 1   1   audi  30000
```

But you are performing a Cartesian product, so if there are multiple value in df1, `e.g: [1,2]`, you will have more duplicate data:

```
id  Brand  Price
0   1  volvo  20000
1   1   audi  30000
2   2  volvo  20000
3   2   audi  30000
```

Comment: it doesnt has multivalue. What if i only want ID 1. which mean I want volvo and audi are under ID1. Like car dataframe is under dataframe 1. Thanks for respond.

Answer (score 0):

This is my current solution:

```
df1={'id':[1]}
df2 = {'Brand':['Volvo','Heizen','Eizen'],
        'Price':[20000,30000,40000]}

person=pd.DataFrame(df1)
car=pd.DataFrame(df2)
id=person.loc[0].id
car.insert(0,"id",id)
print(car)
```

This is my output:

```
   id   Brand  Price
0   1   Volvo  20000
1   1  Heizen  30000
2   1   Eizen  40000
```

It can get my expected table. But is it has any better solution?

Answer (score -1):

df1 and df2 are not Pandas data frames.

```
data1={'id':[1]}
data2={'Brand':['volvo','audi'],'Price':[20000,30000]} 

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1) #creating dataframes
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
frames = [df1,df2]
```

and concatenating

```
pd.concat(frames, sort=False)
```

yields,

```
id  Brand   Price
0   1.0     NaN     NaN
0   NaN     volvo   20000.0
1   NaN     audi    30000.0
```

Comment: That's not the expected output.

Comment: Yes, dfc=person.append(car). It  produce the table some like your propose. So I problem with how i make the car dataframe belong to ID:1 then output my expected table.

Comment: Or maybe is it has any method to process this table become my expected table?